# Eclipse/Flex: update a file every time I launch?

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse

OK my project uses an xml file called `Chart-app.xml` inside this XML file there is a tag called `<version></version>` which I keep in the format like: `<version>1.2.128</version>` I am wondering if I can set it to append to the third number every time I run my project.

So if I ran it now it would be 1.2.129, then if i ran it again it would be 1.2.130

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure there is a native Eclipse way to do this.

You can increment the number within that xml file either:

- programmatically, launching a special class which do that, and then call your primary application Class
- through a dependency during launch, for instance, you can make a JUnit test suite which will first call a Java class doing the increment, and then call your main method.

But in both case, you would have to somehow *code* the increment process.

---

Note: it is easier when you want to [increment something *each time you build*](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg14870.html), because you can add a custom builder.

Answer (score 1):

After reading VonC's answer I don't know anything about ANT or creating custom builds, but he did give me an idea that seems to be working:

I already have a method to tell if the app is running in the ADL (within eclipse), so if it is, I just have my app open the file itself and change the value.